# Identify and style the paragraph beginning w/o a class: based on a combination of common characters (CSS, JS)

Tags: css, javascript, html

There are html-constructions: `<p>— Some random text.</p>`. Without class.

According to the specified attribute "dash, space, some random text.", I need to catch this condition and stylize the paragraph by assigning it a class. For example: `<p class="mdashstring"> — Some random text</p>`. Of course, the goal is that the remaining paragraphs — which do not have a dash and a space at the beginning — should remain as they are.

Through the CSS, this is not solved even by conditional operators. I don't own a javascript, so I ask you to tell me which js code I could use to solve the problem? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, JavaScript will be a good solution for this, although you might get some layout issues since the JavaScript will necessarily have to load in after all your HTML has, which will change the design after the page is loaded.

Comment: That being said, questions on this site should be WordPress-specific. This question would be better asked on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com) (though I can imagine a question like this has already been answered there).

Comment: Yes, I already get the code. This is a good decision:
`document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  document.querySelectorAll('p').forEach(p => {
    if (p.textContent.startsWith('— ')) {
      p.classList.add('mdashstring');
    }
  });
});`